# Integrate a custom map in android application

Tags: android

Want to make custom map of Pakistan that will show districts of each province and by clicking the district it will do some further task. So the problem here is that i want custom map of Pakistan but don't know where to start don't want to use Google Map API. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try ArcGIS, Nutiteq and OpenStreetMaps

Comment: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid try this